# POST request not able to find url

Tags: json, node.js

I am new to nodejs as well as developing. 
I am trying to get a set of data bat from a nutrition site in JSON format. If I formulate the url with my app and api keys along with criteria to paste into the browser I get a JSON data ok. When I try to send a POST request as the site asks for when the request comes back it says it cannot find the url. What it is doing is attaching ':443' to the end of the host url and like I said coming back as an error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search:443
```

What I would like to do is after the end of the url is append the 'postData'.

Here is my code:

```
 var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');


var postData = { // Nutrionix required JSON formt
    "appId":"MY_APP_KEY",
    "appKey":"MY_API_KEY",
    "query": "Lentils",
    "fields": ["item_name", "nf_calories", "nf_serving_size_qty", "nf_serving_size_unit"],
    "sort":{
        "field":"score",
        "order":"desc"
    },
    "filters":{
        "item_type":"2"
    }
};
console.log("This is header dta" + postData);

postBody = querystring.stringify(postData);

var post_options = {
    host:"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search",
    "port":"443",
    method:"post",
    "path":"/",
    headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json",
        'Content-Length': postBody.length
    }
}

console.log(post_options);

var request = https.request(post_options,function(response){
    return response;
});
```

I also am passing this data into the  dev HTTP add-on in Chrome and getting back the proper response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: host:"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search",
    "port":"443",
Aren't you mentioning this in post_options?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I am but even if I remove it I still get the same error. It puts the :443 at the end instead of postData. I added it because I thought it needed to be there. Pasting the URL into a browse returns the site of course with no data and asking for an API key, but if I put the :443 at the end I get 'resource could not be located.

Comment: Can you try this once?  host:"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/". Also remove 443 from the post_options

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I have removed the 443 from the post options and your suggestion and still the same error. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. let me rephrase the suggestion made above. Append "/" at the end of the host url and try again.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I understood sorry I didn't mention it, but yes I did put the "/" at the end of the host url and still the same. This is puzzling because now it adds the ":443" after the "/" anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please take a look at [this documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)?

It seems that you don't need to mention **HTTPS**

Comment: That helped! What I did was change "host" to "hostname" and changed the url to "api.nutritionix.com" and set the path to "/v1_1/search/" and I'm not getting the error anymore of not found. I am however not getting any data back but that is a separate issue I will have to resolve. You did answer my questin. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take the port off, 443 is the default for HTTPS.

Comment: This isn't the issue. There are about 3 things wrong with OP's `post_options`, one being the path in the `host`, and another being the path option is blank. Can you figure out the last issue?

Comment: I did and it's still the same result. It attaches :443 to the end and I get the same error.